# MySQL query get total of payments for everyday of the month until current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a MySQL query to get the total amount for every day of the month until the current date. I'm not sure if it's possible with just one query. It would be something like:

Today's date = '2021-02-24'

```
Select 
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactionDate = '2020-02-01' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Total01,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactionDate = '2020-02-02' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Total03,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactionDate = '2020-02-03' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Total03,
    ...
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactionDate = '2020-02-24' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Total24
From myTable
```

In the end, I would have the total `amount` for every day. Does it make sense?

Thanks

Comment: No. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you mean not possible? Isn't my SQL code in the post? If I need how to create the query, I wouldn't ask. Any reason why you downvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use something like this:

```sql
SELECT
   sum(`amount`) as `amount`, DATE(`transactionDate`) as `date`
FROM
   `myTable`
GROUP BY
   DATE(`transactionDate`)
;
```

This will return rows for each date in database (casted to be only date without time part)

Comment: Thank you. It's what I was looking for. I just added a where condition to filter the date by first date of the month until now.

Comment: I think transactiondate is a date

Comment: No problem, we all started from zero at some point, if you have more questions ask - (thought try to read some sql tutorials earlier;P) and if i have time i will help - it not me, other ppl will too^^